# Graphite: Aggregation Rules not working

Tags: linux, logging, graphite

I have added many aggregation rules like

> app.email.server1.total-sent.1d.sum (86400) = sum app.email.server1.total-sent.1h.sum

I want to know is there any limit on the aggregation rules count. Same kind of other aggregation rules are working.

I checked by using tcpdump also, packets containing the tag `app.email.server1.total-sent.1h.sum` is also coming.

Can we debug by checking logs. I tried but logs is not mentioning anything regarding the type of metrics getting aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum up all 1h to 1d, so in the rule, on the RHS, put * instead of 1h

```
app.email.server1.total-sent.1d.sum (86400) = sum app.email.server1.total-sent.*.sum
```